# $f_{n}$ converges in $L^{1}$ and $\|g_{n}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\leq \|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\implies {g_{n}}$ converges in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f_{n}, g_{n}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ [(Lebesgue space)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). Suppose there exist $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ such that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty;$ that is, the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ converges in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$.
Also, assume that, $\|g_{n}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\leq \|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}$, for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

> **My Question**: What can we say about $g_{n}$; can we expect $g_{n}$ converges in $L^{1}(\mathbb R) $ ? Or, we can produce a counter example ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to expect that the $g_n$ converge, the analogous implication does also not hold in $\mathbb{R}$. For an - admittedly boring - explicit example, take $f_n = \chi_{[0,2]}$ for all $n$ (where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$), and $g_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Evidently the constant sequence $f_n$ converges, but $\lVert g_n - g_m\rVert = 2$ for $m\neq n$.

Comment: @DF; thanks; can we expect the positive answer after putting some  condition on $f_{n}$ and $g_{n}$; like, continuity, etc.;

Comment: No, continuity wouldn't change it. If one imposed that $\lvert g_n(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f_n(x)\rvert$ for all (or almost all) $x$, one may have a chance that not too drastic further restrictions would guarantee the existence of convergent subsequences of $(g_n)$, but I don't see a nice additional condition. With only $\lVert g_n\rVert \leqslant \lVert f_n\rVert$, unless $f_n \to 0$, you basically only have the boundedness of the $g_n$, and that's far too little to get convergence.

Comment: Another variant that would work: $\|g_n-g_m\| \le \|f_n-f_m\|$.